# Register Spring HandlerInterceptor Without WebMvcConfigurationSupport

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to register an instance of `HandlerInterceptor` in Spring using Java Config *without* extending `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`. I'm creating a library with an annotation that, when added to a `@Configuration` class, registers an interceptor that handles a security annotation.

I had an implementation using `WebMvcConfigurationSupport#addInterceptors`, but that conflicted with other automatic workings in spring, and overrode some of the application's own logic. It also seems incredibly heavy for something that should be simple. I'm now trying:

```
@Configuration
public class AnnotationSecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired private RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping;

    @PostConstruct
    public void attachInterceptors() {
        requestMappingHandlerMapping.setInterceptors(new Object[] {
                new SecurityAnnotationHandlerInterceptor()
        });
    }

}
```

However, it appears that the interceptor gets registered with a completely different instance of `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` than the one the application actually uses for web requests. Additionally, when implemeted as a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`, I get a `NullPointerException` in `HealthMvcEndpoint` when I try `beanFactory.getBean(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.class)`

Comment: For reference, this is in `spring-boot-starter-web`

Comment: Also tried a `BeanPostProcessor` to the same effect as the above (the interceptor never gets called)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit**: This class has since been deprecated. See [@bosco answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49983770/683077) below for the Spring 5 equivalent.

Figured it out, the solution is to use, simply:

```
@Configuration
public class AnnotationSecurityConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new SecurityAnnotationHandlerInterceptor());
    }

}
```

In spring boot, all beans of type `WebMvcConfigurer` are automatically detected and can modify the MVC context.

Comment: sicne `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated with spring 5, one should probably use `implements WebMvcConfigurer` (not tested)

Answer (score 14):

Just stating @Blauhirn's comment, [`WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated as of version 5.0](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html):

> Deprecated as of 5.0 `WebMvcConfigurer` has default methods (made possible by a Java 8 baseline) and can be implemented directly without the need for this adapter

Refer to the new way to do it:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new MyCustomInterceptor())
        // Optional
        .addPathPatterns("/myendpoint");
    }
}
```

---

Plus, [as stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31083263/1269558), do not annotate this with `@EnableWebMvc`, if you want to [keep Spring Boot auto configuration for MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration).

Comment: Added an update to my answer to reflect this change. Thanks for the update.