# SpringBoot Rest API custom authentication

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I build a Rest Api using SpringBoot and the authentication I implemented using Firebase.

My problem right now is that I want to have control of the client applications that will access my application. The problem of using SpringSecurity is that as far as I know I have to do the authentication for it and I just want to "allow the client application."

Does anyone have any idea how to do?

Comment: Do you mean that you do not want to perform the authentication for a certain set of clients?

Comment: Do not. All clients must be authenticated, but this task will be the Firebase. On my server I just will check whether the application is authorized to access the server. My problem is precisely verify the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide a unique key to your client. Which your microservice recognises and authenticates any request based on that key. This can be also given as a `request parameter`.

let say you add your key into a parameter called `my-key`, now before working on your logic inside you spring-boot app validate your key. like this -

your Rest Controller would look like this-

```
@RestController
class MyRest{

    private static final String KEY = "someValue";

    @RequestMapping("/some-mapping")
    public @ResponseBody myMethod(@RequestParam(value="my-key", required=true) String key){
        if(!validateRequest(key)){
            //return error as response
        }
        System.out.println("Key Validation Successful!");
        //here goes your logic
    }

    private boolean validateRequest(String key){
        return key.equals(KEY);
    }
}
```

in order to access this rest use - `http://your-host:port/some-mapping?my-key=someValue`

Comment: But where and how I would do this check the key in the Spring?

Comment: This way, anybody can access the APIs. A better way would be to send the data in POST. But again, if the client can send the "key", it can easily use the normal authentication mechanism.

Comment: @yasin - this one is just a showcase of what user can try. other modifications are upto him :)

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. To improve a little will implement a Filter that will filter all requests and verify the key. What do you think?

Comment: Sounds great :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082981/spring-boot-adding-http-request-interceptors - this should come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow some of the clients to bypass the authentication, have a list of whitelisted IP addresses and check the IP of each incoming request. if the IP is in the list of whitelisted APIs, no need to authenticate.

Use `HttpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()` to get the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1

#### Custom interceptor `MyHandlerInterceptor.java`:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class MyHandlerInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    private static final String YOUR_KEY = "KEY_VALUE";

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws IOException {
        String key = request.getHeader("X-Key");
        boolean isValid = YOUR_KEY.equals(key);
        if (!isValid) {
            //invalid key
            response.setStatus(401);
            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
            writer.write("invalid key");
        }
        return isValid;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

#### Configure interceptor `WebConfig.java`:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new MyHandlerInterceptor());
    }
}
```