# Spring boot application. the starter class can not find .xml file

Tags: java, spring-boot

This is my starter application class

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })
@ImportResource("classpath : web.xml")
public class WebPortalApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebPortalApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

this is my project directory structure

[image]

And when I am running the application it prints this

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [classpath : web.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172) ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
```

Can anybody help me in this problem?

Comment: The @ImportResource annotation is for Spring bean definition files.
If you are trying to import a deployment descriptor (as I assume from the name of the file "web.xml"), I suggest you use any of the embedded Tomcat/Jetty/Undertow servers that Spring Boot can provide, so you won't need deployment descriptors anymore. Please see http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-developing-web-applications

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to import `web.xml`  since it is not spring configuration it is a deployment descriptor.

Change project packaging type from `jar` to `war` servlet container should pickup your `web.xml` automatically.

**pom.xml**

```
- <packaging>jar</packaging>
+ <packaging>war</packaging>
```

Answer (score 0):

In spring boot,you don't have to write 'web.xml'  in your spring configuration,you can write like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebPortalApplication{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebPortalApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And you should push your WebPortalApplication.class in the package that you want to manger object of Spring.

Comment: Ok Dear Tom, but what about the all staff in xml files. I switched from mvc to boot, and those 4 xml files do much work: create beans, intercepters, context etc. Now how to do so that all those actions perform its task?

Comment: Well,about this question, you can refer to this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082981/spring-boot-adding-http-request-interceptors.
or spring boot official site,https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/.