# How do I register a HandlerInterceptor with constructor dependencies in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, dependency-injection

My use case is running custom code before a controller method by annotating methods.

HandlerInterceptor seems the way to go but it seems impossible to inject dependencies into it because it needs to be registered before the context is being created.

All examples I've found so far use empty constructors (see [spring boot adding http request interceptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082981/spring-boot-adding-http-request-interceptors/31083263)) or autowire properties in the configuration which fails because I declare dependent beans in the same configuration (Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?).

Is there a better way that does not involve AOP?

Answer (score 2):

Assume that your interceptor has constructor dependencies like that:

```
public class CustomInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptor {

    private final DependentBean bean;

    public CustomInterceptor(DependentBean bean) {
        this.bean = bean;
    }
}
```

Then you can register your handler like that:

```
@Configuration
public WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapater {

    @Bean
    public DependentBean dependentBean() {
       return new DependentBean();
    }


    @Bean
    public CustomInterceptor customInterceptor() {
         return new CustomInterceptor(dependentBean());
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
         registry.addInterceptor(customInterceptor());
    }
}
```

`@Configuration` will ensure each `Bean` method call return the same bean instance

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't work for me since DependentBean has a longer dependency chain and is resolved via component scan. One of DependentBean's dependencies' dependencies is declared in the same file and causes the circular reference exception.

Comment: No. Put them in @Configuration, the bean will resolved coẻctly. If you are in situation that two bean reference each other then it's time to make the wrapper bean, which depends on both beans

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer above from Mạnh, if using component scan for dependency injection of the dependency, then that can be Autowired in the WebConfig

```
@Configuration
public WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapater {

    @Autowired
    DependentBean dependentBean;

    @Bean
    public CustomInterceptor customInterceptor() {
         return new CustomInterceptor(dependentBean);
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
         registry.addInterceptor(customInterceptor());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also building on previous answers, and if you use Lombok, you can further simplify.

1. Have your interceptor implementation been a `@Component`
2. Add a `private final DependentBean` field to it.
3. Also add a `@RequiredArgsConstructor` annotation to it, to have Lombok generating a constructor with a single `DependentBean` parameter.
4. In your `WebConfig`, use the same technic to have a `private final CustomInterceptor` field been injected by Spring IOC.

This way the CustomInterceptor instance will be available & initialized the right way when `addInterceptors` will be called

---

Here are the corresponding code samples :

---

###### The `CustomInterceptor` :

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    private final DependentBean dependentBean;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle( final HttpServletRequest request,
                              final HttpServletResponse response,
                              final Object handler ) throws Exception {
        // your Interceptor Implementation goes here ...
    }
}
```

###### The `WebConfig` :

```java
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final CustomInterceptor customInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors( final InterceptorRegistry registry ) {
        registry.addInterceptor( customInterceptor );
    }
}
```