# Why does the spring boot controller not invoked after calling request.getReader in preHandle

Tags: spring, spring-boot, interceptor

I am implementing an interceptor for logging purposes. I know once i called the getReader method on HttpServletRequest will loose the body data, but i was experimenting. So i ran the below code, and realized the controller is never invoked (Debug point is not activated) and there was no errors.

```
@Component
public class IncomingRequestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {

        String requestPayload = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
        System.out.println(requestPayload);
        return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)
            throws Exception {

        super.afterCompletion(request, response, handler, ex);
    }

}
```

And the controller

```
    @PostMapping("/test")
    public String test(@Valid @RequestBody CredentialsVo credentials) {

        credentials.getUsername();
        .............

        return "test";
    }
```

Filter Registration

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    IncomingRequestInterceptor incomingRequestInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
            registry.addInterceptor(incomingRequestInterceptor)
              .addPathPatterns("/**");
    }

}
```

if i do not call getReader() method, the controller is invoked. I was actually expecting the controller is called but i would get a null pointer or something like that. 
Could anyone tell me how spring acts in this scenario ?

Comment: I think you need to register your interceptor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082981/spring-boot-adding-http-request-interceptors

Comment: And remember i spring 5 it is called WebMvcConfigurer and not WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Hello, i have already registered it, i have updated my question. The problem is preHandle is invoked, but not the controller.

Comment: Because the body is already consumed, there is no way to call the method and create a `CredentialsVo`. Basically there is nothing left to invoke the method with.