# Spring boot 2 - how do I get all response headers being sent to client?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I've tried adding in a `Filter` and the `response.getHeaderNames()` doesn't have anything.

I've also tried adding in a `@ControllerAdvice` to a class that implements `ResponseBodyAdvice` and doing a `response.getHeaders()` on the `ServerHttpResponse` object - it says it has no headers. But when I curl an endpoint, I see lots of headers being returned.

How do I get all headers from a response in Spring Boot? Additionally, there doesn't seem to be a way to get the returned HTTP protocol from a response either.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: You can use spring aop.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45585071/12075726

The interceptor's aftercomplete method had all the headers that were about to be sent to the client.