# Is there an equivalent of @before and @after in @RestControllers?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, spring-restcontroller

I have a rest controller API in a spring boot project. I need to add a common function, for example, validating the token of each incoming request before all the routes in that controller rather than calling the same function separately for each routes. Is there a way to achieve that with @Restcontroller based routing instead of going with web flux handler and router way?

Edit: Is there a way to use interceptors only for certain routes rather than all incoming requests?

Current version example:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/")
class TestController() {

@GetMapping("/test1")
fun test1(): String {
  common()
  return "Test1"
 }
 @GetMapping("/test2")
 fun test2(): String {
   common()
   return "Test2"
 }

 fun common() {
   //some validation logic
 }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot Adding Http Request Interceptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082981/spring-boot-adding-http-request-interceptors)

Comment: You can use a `HandlerINterceptor` for that. But as this feels like you are attempting to build your own security solution, I would strongly suggest to use Spring Security instead of building your own framework.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I need to use the token mechanism for only certain routes, for example, only the routes under " /externalapi/* ".  other routes may or may not use the same security measures. Instead of using interceptors for all http requests, is there a way to filter out only certain routes?

Answer (score 0):

you normally develop filters to deal with security on Springboot. Filters intercept all calls made to your application where you can check the existence of a token avoiding unauthorized access. Please refer to this page for more grained details: https://medium.com/@xoor/jwt-authentication-service-44658409e12c.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But i was looking for adding interceptor for one specific controller routes rather than all incoming http requests.