# Intellj pro: how to know a request is intercepted, advised by which beans?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellj pro. My project is a spring boot mvc application. The support for spring mvc application is so good. However i can not find a way to know how many beans, interceptors or filters that affect a request mapping. Is there anyway to know this with Intellj pro?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55901453/9968399) answers your question?

Comment: Have you checked the [Spring tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-diagrams.html#spring-tool-window)?