# Interceptor not able to receive requests in spring boot version 1.5.8

Tags: spring-boot, interceptor

I have an application which uses quite an old version of spring boot. I have applied interceptor in the application but request is not coming to the interceptor.

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public GenericInterceptor genericInterceptor() {
    return new GenericInterceptor();
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(genericInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**");
}}
```

The bean returned class is GenericInterceptor declared below.

```
public class GenericInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter{
    // custom logic 
}
```

The main spring boot class is defined below

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebMvc
public class TestApplication implements WebApplicationInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
}}
```

Request is not coming to the Generic Interceptor. Is this because of @EnableWebMvc or something is missing.
Can someone explain ?

Comment: Try adding `@EnableWebMvc` for `public class TestConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` instead of the `TestApplication`

Answer (score 0):

You should put `@EnableWebMvc` for the `@Configuration` as the document said:

> Adding this annotation to an @Configuration class imports the Spring
> MVC configuration from WebMvcConfigurationSupport

and

> Note: only one @Configuration class may have the @EnableWebMvc
> annotation to import the Spring Web MVC configuration. There can
> however be multiple @Configuration classes implementing
> WebMvcConfigurer in order to customize the provided configuration

Try the code below:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class TestConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public GenericInterceptor genericInterceptor() {
        return new GenericInterceptor();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(genericInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**");
    }
}
```

Comment: does the spring auto configuration will not provide webmvc support. saw this in this ans:  NOTE do not annotate this with @EnableWebMvc, if you want to keep Spring Boots auto configuration for mvc. Can you elaborate on this ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082981/spring-boot-adding-http-request-interceptors